# Coding Interval Point calculator more efficiently in python

Tags: python-3.x

I've been trying to code a function that takes variables a and b which are start and end points and calculate how far to go from a to b as a fraction between 0 and 1. (That fraction is variable x).

The code I have partially works, but it does not always work properly with negative numbers. For example if `a = -2` and `b = -1` and `x = 1` the output should be -1 but I get -2.

I have been solving similar problems thus far using `if` statements but I don't want to continue like this. Is there a more elegant solution?

```
def interval_point(a, b, x):
        """Given parameters a, b and x. Takes three numbers and interprets a and b
        as the start and end point of an interval, and x as a fraction
        between 0 and 1 that returns how far to go towards b, starting at a"""
        if a == b:
            value = a
        elif a < 0 and b < 0 and x == 0:
            value = a
        elif a < 0 and b < 0:
            a1 = abs(a)
            b1 = abs(b)
            value = -((a1-b1) + ((a1-b1)*x))
        else:
            value = (a + (b-a)*x)
        return(value)
```

Comment: you can combine the conditions first `elif` and second `elif`, and write a nested structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have played around with the maths somewhat and I have arrived at a much simpler way of solving the problem.

This is what the function now looks like:

```
def interval_point(a, b, x):
    """Given parameters a, b and x. Takes three numbers and interprets a and b
    as the start and end point of an interval, and x as a fraction
    between 0 and 1 that returns how far to go towards b, starting at a"""
    return((b - a) * x + a)
```